# virtual box error(Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)) after updating my ubuntu precise 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, kernel, virtualbox

i use windows over virtualbox in my ubuntu precise version
when i was working, some updates popped up and i updated my os..

and since then, i am not able to run my virtual box..
whenever i start my windows, it keeps giving me the following error

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
```

i tried everything, 
uninstalled and installed virtual box, updated kernel headers.. tried everything but in vain..
can anyone help me out here please?

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

it asks me to execute the following command

```
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

but when i do that, it says command not found,
what do i do?

this is what i get

```
Failed to create a new virtual machine.
```

Machine settings file '/home/kiran/VirtualBox VMs/win 7/win 7.vbox' already exists.

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}
Callee: IVirtualBox {c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66}

Comment: how did you install Virtual Box? Use the deb package. Try re-installing, since `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` is part of the deb package

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall virtualbox guest additions , Then re install it